# Jruby 1.6.8 tomcat deployment issue (org.jruby.rack.rails.RailsServletContextListener)

Tags: java, tomcat7, jruby, jrubyonrails, warbler

I'm trying to deploy a JoR application with a war file built using warbler-0.9.14 to Tomcat 7. However when I try and start the app, I get the following error

> Jul 09, 2016 3:48:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
>   SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.jruby.rack.rails.RailsServletContextListener
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.destroy(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:58)
>       at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(RackServletContextListener.java:50)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5146)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5810)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1312)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:690)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:216)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

:

I just don't know enough about Java/jruby to know what I'm missing. Any help or reference to any docs would be very appreciated. The codebase is very old and there is no documentation. I've determined that it's using jruby-1.6.8 and rails 2.3.5.

Here's the web.xml

```html
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>rails.env</param-name>
    <param-value>development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>public.root</param-name>
    <param-value>/</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>jruby.min.runtimes</param-name>
    <param-value>2</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>jruby.max.runtimes</param-name>
    <param-value>4</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jruby.rack.rails.RailsServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Rails</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jruby.rack.RackServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Rails</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/servlets/image</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>Forbidden</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
          <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
          <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
          <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint />
  </security-constraint>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jruby-rack was the problem. The version of warbler I was using was really old, so I ended up upgrading to 1.4.9 which upgraded jruby-rack to jruby-rack-1.1.20.jar.